# Unable to update Teams tab app name for existing tab instance

Tags: microsoft-teams-js

I have small test program for creating teams tab app.

```
app.initialize().then( async () => {
        /**
         * When the user clicks "Save", save the url for your configured tab.
         * This allows for the addition of query string parameters based on
         * the settings selected by the user.
         */

        // Start reading context information.
        const teamsContext = await getTeamsContext();

        // Set theme.
        setTheme( teamsContext?.app?.theme ?? "default" );

        const conf = await pages.getConfig();

        let tabId = "";

        pages.config.registerOnSaveHandler( ( saveEvent ) => {

            // Get tab name.
            const input = document.getElementById( "tab-name" ) as HTMLInputElement;
            const tabName = input && input.value.trim() !== "" ? input.value : "Test";

            pages.config
                .setConfig( {
                    websiteUrl: window.location.origin,
                    contentUrl: window.location.origin + "/Home/Index/",
                    removeUrl: window.location.origin + "/Home/Remove",
                    entityId: tabId,
                    suggestedDisplayName: tabName
                } )
                .then( () => {
                    saveEvent.notifySuccess();
                } );
        } );

        if ( conf.entityId ) {
            tabId = conf.entityId
            updateTabName( conf.suggestedDisplayName );
        }
        else {
            tabId = createGuid();
        }

        /**
         * After verifying that the settings for your tab are correctly
         * filled in by the user you need to set the state of the dialog
         * to be valid.  This will enable the save button in the configuration
         * dialog.
         */
        pages.config.setValidityState( true );

        // Hide the loading indicator.
        app.notifySuccess();
    } );
```

I would like to update the name for existing tab instance.

I tried to use the above functionality but the `suggestedDisplayName` has not affect when updating existing tab and would like to know is the manual renaming the only way to change tab name.